# Cannot resolve ListView in Adapter class

Tags: android

I want to implement a dialog box in on click of listitem of list view in my adapter class. How can I access my `ListView` from another class?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
    adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
    adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = " + listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    adb.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
    adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
    adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = " + getItem(position));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    adb.show();
}
```

or implement `onItemClick()` listener in your activity/fragment containing the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you make in your Adapter class. Use `listview.setOnItemClickListener(this)` in your activity or fragment.

or

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code uses `onClick`, you should have `onItemClick`.

Your code will look like this:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) parent.getAdapter; // use your actual adapter class name here

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
            adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
            adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = " + adapter.getItem(position));
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            adb.show();
        }
    });
```

And make sure you have a proper implementation of `getItem` in your adapter.